# Turn off autocomplete after $this in phpStorm

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

I've just installed phpStorm 9 and it autocompletes the "arrow" (don't know if it has a proper name) after typing `$this` in a class. So when I type `$this-` is autocompletes it to `$this->`. It should be a simple issue but I haven't been able to figure out how to turn this off. I've tried *Smart Keys*, *Intentions* and every possible setting I could find but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have a solution? I'm sure it's obvious but I'm just missing it.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such setting. What kind of issues do you have with current behaviour?

Comment: It just bothers me :) I'm used to older versions (even 8.0 I think), where it didn't do this, so it's a bit disconcerting. But I guess I can get used to it if there's no other way…

Comment: How did you typed in in first place (I mean -- in old version). I, for example, use custom Live Template that expands `t[TAB]` into `$this->` with forcing code completion popup to show up. With that I have no need to type `$this` at all...

Comment: In the old version I typed `$this-` and it wrote `$this-`; now I type `$this-` and it writes `$this->`. If I type the extra `>` afterwards it doesn't type `$this->>` so the completion is smart. I would however like it to write exactly what I type when I type it.

Comment: If anything -- feel free to file new ticket at [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI). Considering that completion is smart and typing `$this->` results in actual `$this->` then I do not really see the reason for additional setting to turn it off. If you find places or situations where such completion does not work well or brings bugs .. then file it as a bug so devs can fix such behaviour. Just keep in mind that current behaviour is what quite a few people have asked for -- to speed up their code completions (to type `>` you need to press extra `Shift` key)

Comment: I thought about filing a ticket but it's not really a bug. More of a quirk of mine. Anyway, thanks for answering. At least I won't be wasting any more time looking for a setting which doesn't exist.